# how to get the min and max of a multi dim array (with one dim is specified) in c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a multi dimensions array ins C# defined as follow:

```
 double[,,] myArray=new double[10000,10000,3];
```

I find the maximum value of this array when the last dim is for example is 0. something g such as this:

```
 double m1=myArray[?,?,0].Max();
```

How can I calculate it using Linq or other methods?

Comment: multidimensional arrays suck. (in c#)

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to get the max across some subset of the array you can do this:

```
double m1 = 
    (from x in Enumerable.Range(0, myArray.GetLength(0))
     from y in Enumerable.Range(0, myArray.GetLength(1))
     select myArray[x, y, 0])
    .Max();
```

If you'd like to get the max across all elements in the array you can just do this

```
double m1 = myArray.Cast<double>().Max();
```

However, you can get a significant performance boost by implementing your own extension method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this T[,,] arry) {
    foreach(T x in arry) yield return item;
}

myArray.Flatten().Max();
```

Comment: there's also [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) - would that work instead of `Flatten`?

Comment: @Default That would only work for jagged arrays (`double[][]`).

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 2**

Note, this extension works equally well for the hideous but valid case of a non zero based array,

```
var nonZeroBasedArray = Array.CreateInstance(
    typeof(double),
    new[] { 4, 4, 3 },
    new[] { -2, -2, 0 });
```

Note that the first two dimensions range from `-2` to `1` inclusive (yikes.) This test code illustrates that the `Flatten` extension still works.

```
var count = 0;
foreach (var element in nonZeroBasedArray.Flatten<double>(null, null, 0))
{
    Console.Write(string.Join(", ", element.Key));
    Console.WriteLine(": {0}", element.Value);
}

Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}", count);
Console.ReadKey();
```

---

**EDIT**

So, using the extension defined below you can do

```
var myArray = new double[10000,10000,3];
var ordered = myArray.Flatten<double>(null, null, 0).OrderBy(p => p.Value);
var maxZ0 = ordered.First();
var minZ0 = ordered.Last();
```

The element type is a `KeyValuePair<IEnumerable<int>, T>` so the `Key` allows you to back reference to the original array.

---

Ok, here is a generic extension, intially inspired by [p.s.w.g's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17042064/659190)

If you start with [Eric Lippert's inspirational `CartesianProduct<T>` extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx),

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(
        this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) =>
            from accseq in accumulator
            from item in sequence
            select accseq.Concat(new[]
                {
                    item
                }));
}
```

Then you make a function to generate the bound sets of a multi dimensional array that allows you to specify fixed values for some dimensions.

```
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GetBoundSequences(
        Array array,
        int?[] definedBounds)
{
    for (var rank = 0; rank < array.Rank; rank++)
    {
        var defined = definedBounds.ElementAtorDefault(rank);

        if (defined.HasValue)
        {
            yield return new[] { defined.Value };
        }
        else
        {
            var min = array.GetLowerBound(rank);
            yield return Enumerable.Range(
                min, 
                (array.GetUpperBound(rank) - min) + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

you can use both to make a flexible `Flatten<T>` extension, that works with arrays of any rank.

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<IEnumerable<int>, T>> Flatten<T>(
        this Array array,
        params int?[] definedBounds)
{
    var coordSets = GetBoundSequences(array, definedBounds).CartesianProduct();
    foreach (var coordSet in coordSets)
    {
        var coords = coordSet.ToArray();
        var value = (T)array.GetValue(coords);
        yield return new KeyValuePair<IEnumerable<int>, T>(
            coords,
            value);
    }
}
```

Once you have this, you can do something like

```
var myArray = new double[10000,10000,3];
var maxZ0 = myArray.Flatten<double>(null, null, 0).Max(p => p.Value);
```

This is good because it lazily iterates and converts only the elements specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
double[,,] myArray = new double[10000, 10000, 3];

double max = myArray.Cast<double>().Max();
```

Comment: But it returns max of all items in array. I need max of items when the last dim index is 0